# hero card image attachment not loading

Tags: c#, botframework, attachment

I am using the code

```
private static Attachment HeroCard() {
   var hc = new HeroCard {
      Images=new List<CardImage> {
         new CardImage(@"C:\Users\.....\imgs\testImage.jpg") }
      };
    return hc.ToAttachment();
}
```

To load an image in a hero card's attachment. This works fine but if
I try to use the local folder instead e.x

```
@"~\imgs\testImage.jpg"
```

The image fails to load. I have tried different other formats regarding 
the path with no success. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try to use the local folder `@"~\imgs\testImage.jpg"`

It seems that your image files are stored in your project `imgs` folder and you’d like to send the image to client. You can try to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` to read MapPath. The following code works for me, please refer to it.

```
var hc = new HeroCard
{
    Images = new List<CardImage> {
    new CardImage(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\imgs\testImage.jpg"))
}
};
```

Comment: Didn't know about this. Image is loading now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Down below code work on MS Bot Framework **SDK v4**

```
var imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\testImage.png");
var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));

var heroCard = new ThumbnailCard
{
    Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage($"data:image/png;base64,{imageData}") },
};
```

You can find more examples about working with attachments [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/Bots/AttachmentsBot.cs)

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue. I was just using: `Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(imageData) }`, wondering why didn't this work.